# Convert sql query into linq

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can i convert below sql query into linq?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.Archived = '1' THEN 1  END) As ACount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.IsImportant = '1' and P.Archived = '0' THEN 1  
END) As ICount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.CreatedById = 1389 and P.Archived = '0' THEN 1 END) As CCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.CreatedById != 1389 and P.Archived = '0' THEN 1 END) As SCount,
    COUNT(*) as TotalThreatModelsCount
FROM Parties P
```

Comment: If you have working SQL, I'd keep the working SQL and use `ExecuteQuery<>()`. Translating this to linq gains you nothing.

Comment: I agree @JoelCoehoorn, plus once you start getting complex with LINQ it can start doing unexpected query plans quickly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i am using EFcore so how do i achieve using ExecuteQuery<>(). any suggestion with example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score -2):

This won't result in the same exact query, as it will result in 5 separate queries to the database, but it will give the same results.

```
    using (YourContext context = new YourContext())
    {
        int ACount = context.Parties.Count(_ => _.Archived == "1");
        int ICount = context.Parties.Count(_ => _.IsImportant == "1" &&  _.Archived == "0");
        int CCount = context.Parties.Count(_ => _.CreatedById == 1389 && _.Archived == "0");
        int SCount = context.Parties.Count(_ => _.CreatedById != 1389 && _.Archived == "0");
        int TotalThreadModelsCount = context.Parties.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Five separate queries to the database is more than just a little inefficient for this.

Comment: it's 5 separate queries for one connection, so the inefficiency is minimal. The execution plans would also be simpler than if you tried to get linq to answer all questions in a single statement.